# SharePoint custom permissions Check in/Check out issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, check-out, check-in, edit-update-delete

I have a SharePoint 2013 site, which has no versioning set on the specific document library. I have a custom permission level, which does not allow users to ‘Delete items’. This works great until you want to edit a document in the office client and then save back again.

So, if I edit a word document and then tries to save, it requests me to complete the properties(this is correct as they are required). Once these properties have been completed and I tries to save it again, it requests me to check in the document.

If a user who has ‘Delete items’ permission(Contribute level for example) does the same action then they do not get requested to check in the document in and can save it.

Is anyone aware if there is any other specific permission level that will avoid the Check-In requirement on a document? I do not want to give users the rights to delete items.

Looking forward to hear from someone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to copy the contribution permission level and uncheck the delete items only, then try to edit the document

[image]